# Is it possible to merge an old and new data.SE login?

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

Today I tried to log in on https://data.stackexchange.com/ using my regular Yahoo account but was unable to. I get:

> No OpenID endpoint found.

When I log in using the Stack Exchange option I get a new account.

I don't want to lose the queries from my old account. Is it possible to merge an old and new account?

Comment: [Data Explorer created a new account; issuing an account merge request resulted in a server error](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/311580). The only solution is to *somehow* try to login with your Yahoo account.