# It's time to remove Yahoo login from https://data.stackexchange.com/

Tags: bug, data-explorer, login, yahoo

Follow up question to:

[Is it possible to merge an old and new data.SE login?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333080/163529)

I was able to log in few days after asking that question.

Now I am unable to log in with Yahoo which is how I log into my regular SO account. It’s been 2 months plus, and I’m still unable to log in.

It still gives me the message:

> No OpenID endpoint found.

Comment: Try to add Google login on any site (e.g. here), then you should be able to use it on SEDE to login.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask Why I login with google when my SO account  associate with yahoo?

Comment: Because looks like SEDE can't work with Yahoo anymore. It's not a solution, it's a work around.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to use this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353406/stack-exchange-data-explorer-login-is-changing ?