# Slightly misleading title on SEDE login page

Tags: bug, data-explorer, login, openid

The [login page](https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login?returnurl=/) of the Stack Exchange Data Explorer says "Log in with OpenID", but that pertains to just the bottom part of the options; [Stack Exchange itself doesn't provide OpenID authentication anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/295232), login is based on OAuth2 and AFAICT this is also true for the Google login.

[image]

Can the title be changed to "Log in with OAuth2 or OpenID" or perhaps just "Log in"?

Comment: Or "Log in with one of these options"

Comment: While we are at it: Does Yahoo! still works? It doesn't for me. Visiting https://me.yahoo.com/ isn't hopeful either , Reported earlier: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353153/

Comment: That label is set [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L46) but it is different for anonymous / logged in users. In the logged in state you end up there from your profile when you click "change openid".  That whole account management / login code is brittle  as hell in SEDE and has a history of happily creating a new account while never being able to regain access your old profile so I rather not experiment with what does and doesn't work there.